# populate xml in dropdown with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, xml, drop-down-menu

i want to populate a xml with jquery. i got the following code:

jquery:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "GHworkerType.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find('type').each(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var name = $(this).find('name').text();
                var rate = $(this).find('rate').text();
                $('<div id="link_' + id + '"></div>').html('<a href="' + name + '">' + type + '</a>').appendTo('#WorkerTypeDropDownList');

            });
        }
    });
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worker>
    <type id=0>
        <name>Fitter, mechanical or electrician</name>
        <rate>75</rate>
    </type>
</worker>
```

html:

```
<select id="WorkerTypeDropDownList">
      <option>loading</option>
</select>
```

how can i populate this xml now? i want the user to select one of the items and pass the value(rate) to a variable to my codebehind (C#).

i also want to populate this xml to another dropdownlist. but in this case i want to change the rate. how can i get this to work?

greetz

Tobi

EDIT:

this is the code which is running:

js:

```
$.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: "GHworkerType.xml",
                                dataType: "xml",
                                success: function (xml) {
                                    var select = $('#comboWorkerType');
                                    $(xml).find('type').each(function () {
                                        type = $(this).find('type').text();
                                        select.append("" + type + "");
                                        id = $(this).attr('id');
                                        name = $(this).find('name').text();
                                        rate = $(this).find('rate').text();
//                                        alert(rate);
                                        $('<option>' + name + '</option>').html('<option' + type + '">' + name + '</option>').appendTo('#comboWorkerType');
                                    });
                                    //                    alert($('#comboWorkerType option:selected').text());

                                    select.children(":first").text("Select worker type").attr("selected", true);

                                }
```

xml:

```
<type>
    <name>Fitter, mechanical or electrician</name>
    <rate>75</rate>
</type>
```

html:

```
<select id="comboWorkerType" >
     <option>Select worker type</option>
</select>
```

but i want to get the rate of the selected item to my codebehind.

how can i get this to run?

greetz

tobi

Comment: can you use [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)? they've kinda already implemented this for you

Comment: and how is this working. i'm curently use some of the widgets of jqueryui.

Comment: They have a remote-data source sample there, which explains how to use extrernal data source(such as ajax) to get the items. Note, it wont look like a combobox but like an autocomplete texboxt. theres also a  combobox sample there (look at the menu on the right side of the screen)

Comment: could you give me an example hot to implement this to my site? i'm really new to jquery and jquery ui :-)

Comment: the combobox is displayed but xmldata isn't bind to the combobox. any hints how i can get it to work?

Comment: you need to add the xml values to the select, but you should add them as option tags and not divs, as you've done in your provided code.

Comment: i think just substitute the div tags with option tags in the last line isn't enough. the combobox still displays 'loading'. what else is missing?

Comment: i don't got no idea how i can get it to work. could it be the wrong directory for the xml? i put it to the same directory as my .aspx. it still shows loading

Comment: finally the xml is shown in my combobox. but how can i passthrough the 'rate' to the codebehind?